# SpriteKit and UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Does the `SpriteKitView` have to be set to the view property of the `UIViewController`. Is it not possible to add it to a view within a nested `UIViewController`?

Whenever I try this it does not appear however the `SpriteKitScene` is running as messages output to the console informing that updates are occurring within the nodes of the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this (see image below)?

SKView inherits from UIView so, like any other view, it is possible to combine it with other views in the view hierarchy.

If your SKScene is created but not appearing, maybe you forgot to call presentScene for your scene?

[image: SKView as child]